# WPF how to draw a picture of the figure

Tags: c#, wpf, image, canvas, path

```
<Canvas>
            <Path Name="theEllipse" Fill="Red">
                <Path.Data>
                    <PathGeometry  Figures="M458.118,329.491L456.69599999999997,329.038L452.56199999999995,323.35L451.15299999999996,322.521L447.604,322.262L445.67699999999996,318.67L443.99899999999997,319.65700000000004L442.972,321.29300000000006L441.614,321.44300000000004L441.10999999999996,320.77900000000005L436.25399999999996,319.62000000000006L435.114,320.20000000000005L429.28799999999995,319.605L428.55999999999995,317.956L428.27599999999995,312.391L428.4789999999999,310.523L430.1459999999999,310.057L431.5469999999999,311.322L431.8809999999999,310.79L431.4789999999999,309.25600000000003L432.5969999999999,306.11600000000004L433.2949999999999,305.63100000000003L433.3059999999999,305.62500000000006L434.2629999999999,309.41800000000006L435.38499999999993,309.75800000000004L436.4789999999999,310.72700000000003L439.2289999999999,310.22100000000006L439.43699999999995,309.30500000000006L440.99899999999997,308.8550000000001L442.383,307.5570000000001L442.823,306.4840000000001L442.397,298.78800000000007L447.972,296.2270000000001L450.161,296.13900000000007L453.442,298.88500000000005L455.271,299.23600000000005L455.172,300.37200000000007L458.05400000000003,303.59600000000006L459.069,304.19800000000004L461.36600000000004,302.61100000000005L462.547,302.96500000000003L462.50800000000004,303.663L463.97600000000006,304.225L464.41600000000005,304.084L465.60800000000006,305.284L467.26700000000005,305.102L467.10300000000007,306.959L468.20000000000005,307.693L467.1940000000001,312.643L466.4720000000001,312.616L466.1850000000001,313.594L466.8060000000001,314.09999999999997L467.7330000000001,313.26L469.0580000000001,313.842L468.6100000000001,315.459L469.3080000000001,315.939L470.3880000000001,320.79L470.0470000000001,323.06100000000004L468.4440000000001,323.82200000000006L465.82900000000006,326.8930000000001L465.89400000000006,328.5340000000001L463.41100000000006,328.4630000000001L462.23300000000006,327.4840000000001L460.59400000000005,327.6780000000001L459.5690000000001,329.04500000000013Z">
                    </PathGeometry>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
```

How the center of the figure to draw a picture?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried and what the results were?

Comment: makes no sense to me .. !

Comment: Can you use some words to describe your problem please?

Answer (score 0):

Add please :  `Stretch="Fill"`

```
 <Path Name="theEllipse"  Fill="Red" Stretch="Fill" >
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry  Figures="M458.118,329.491L456.69599999999997,329.038L452.56199999999995,323.35L451.15299999999996,322.521L447.604,322.262L445.67699999999996,318.67L443.99899999999997,319.65700000000004L442.972,321.29300000000006L441.614,321.44300000000004L441.10999999999996,320.77900000000005L436.25399999999996,319.62000000000006L435.114,320.20000000000005L429.28799999999995,319.605L428.55999999999995,317.956L428.27599999999995,312.391L428.4789999999999,310.523L430.1459999999999,310.057L431.5469999999999,311.322L431.8809999999999,310.79L431.4789999999999,309.25600000000003L432.5969999999999,306.11600000000004L433.2949999999999,305.63100000000003L433.3059999999999,305.62500000000006L434.2629999999999,309.41800000000006L435.38499999999993,309.75800000000004L436.4789999999999,310.72700000000003L439.2289999999999,310.22100000000006L439.43699999999995,309.30500000000006L440.99899999999997,308.8550000000001L442.383,307.5570000000001L442.823,306.4840000000001L442.397,298.78800000000007L447.972,296.2270000000001L450.161,296.13900000000007L453.442,298.88500000000005L455.271,299.23600000000005L455.172,300.37200000000007L458.05400000000003,303.59600000000006L459.069,304.19800000000004L461.36600000000004,302.61100000000005L462.547,302.96500000000003L462.50800000000004,303.663L463.97600000000006,304.225L464.41600000000005,304.084L465.60800000000006,305.284L467.26700000000005,305.102L467.10300000000007,306.959L468.20000000000005,307.693L467.1940000000001,312.643L466.4720000000001,312.616L466.1850000000001,313.594L466.8060000000001,314.09999999999997L467.7330000000001,313.26L469.0580000000001,313.842L468.6100000000001,315.459L469.3080000000001,315.939L470.3880000000001,320.79L470.0470000000001,323.06100000000004L468.4440000000001,323.82200000000006L465.82900000000006,326.8930000000001L465.89400000000006,328.5340000000001L463.41100000000006,328.4630000000001L462.23300000000006,327.4840000000001L460.59400000000005,327.6780000000001L459.5690000000001,329.04500000000013Z">
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
```

Comment: I dont understand, why you vote down ? You tried to solve the problem ? You understant what the user asks? Try to put in VS the sample and you will see what is the problem and how I solve it :)

Comment: I have a lot of figures and each need to enter the picture. Maybe it is necessary to calculate the center of the figure?

Comment: I don't know how can  the center of the figure can help. If you don`t set Stretch = Fill or Uniform, the figure will be rendered on bottom-right every time. If you set this property, the figure will fit in canvas. If you have more figures, set for all of them the mentioned property and it will work